# How to find out how many cores (including emulated via HT and such) are avaliable to user?

Tags: shell-script, cpu, multiprocessor

I wonder how to get how many cores (including emulated via HT and such) are avaliable to user via bash shell-script command?

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: Debian, Ubuntu, OpenSuse, MacOsX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux:

```
grep ^processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
```

Comment: Or try `grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo` and you won't need to spawn two processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `nproc` or `nproc --all`.